# How do you copy an inline style element in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

IE does not allow writing to the innerHTML property of style or head elements. So how do you copy a style element from the head of one document to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copy_style(src_style_tag) {    
    var tmp_div = document.createElement('div');
    var innerHTML = src_style_tag.innerHTML;
    tmp_div.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><style type="text/css">' + innerHTML + '</style>';

    return tmp_div.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
}
```

The magic is that you need the `<p>` tag in the `innerHTML` of the `tmp_div`. Without it, IE does not accept the style element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy some elements, than try using [Node.cloneNode(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) together with [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Comment: cloneNode does not work from a different document (say an iframe). You would need to use document.importNode, which is not supported by IE.