# Adding a style tag to a page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, coding-style

I'm trying to add some styles into a page using javascript

```
var style = document.createElement("style"),
style.innerHTML = ".firstChildTest div:first-child {width: 2px;}";
```

But ie6-8 are throwing an error when trying to use innerHTML on a style element. I also get the same error using

```
 style.append(document.createTextNode(".firstChildTest div:first-child {width: 2px;}"));
```

How do I inject styles into a style element in ie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here: [How do you copy an inline style element in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875610/how-do-you-copy-an-inline-style-element-in-ie)

```
function copy_style(style_text) {    
    var tmp_div = document.createElement('div');
    tmp_div.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><style type="text/css">' + style_text + '</style>';

    return tmp_div.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
}
```

Note that you need the `<p>` tag in the innerHTML of the tmp_div. Without it, IE does not accept the style element.

Comment: Very odd quirk to be able to create a new style element you can't then do anything with. Cheers for the answer

Comment: @wheresrhys You can insert the style DOM element this produces into the document tree.

Comment: What I meant is that document.createElement("style") is an odd quirk - your function works great. cheers

Answer (score 0):

IE before #9 cannot use childNodes to add text to a style (or script or option) element,
And styles are supposed to be in the head of an html document.

```
function addStyle(str){
    var el= document.createElement('style');
    if(el.styleSheet) el.styleSheet.cssText= str;
    else{
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    }
    return document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
}
```